# Need to clarify the "At-least Concept" in Combination.

Tags: combinatorics

I managed to solve this question but I had some inquiries regarding the solution.

> > If two cards are chosen at random from a standard deck of playing cards, how many different ways are there to draw the two cards if at least one card is a jack, queen or a king?

Here is how I solved it:

Jack/Queen/King = $4 \times 3 = 12$ cards

Other Cards = $52-12 = 40$ cards

Now we can only pick two cards so:

- It can be either from the Jack/King/Queen so $\binom{12}{1}=12$
- Both cards can be from Jack/King/Queen so $\binom{12}{2} = 66$
- One card can be from the remaining stack (Non - jack,king or queen) so
  $\binom{40}{1}=40$

Now the only problem I have with this question is when getting the final value initially I was doing

$1$ from Remaining Cards $\times$ [  ($1$ from Jack/King/Queen) + 2(from Jack/King/Queen) ]= $\binom{40}{1} \times (  \binom{12}{1} + \binom{12}{2} ) $

But The actual answer comes if we do the following

[$1$ from Remaining Cards $\times$  $1$ from Jack/King/Queen ] + 2(from Jack/King/Queen) ]= $( \binom{40}{1} \times   \binom{12}{1}) + \binom{12}{2}  $

I would really appreciate it if someone could clarify why do we do it the second way and not the first way ? Which part is added/multiplied to which part ? Is there an easier way to know how its done. Am I missing some important concept here ?

**Edit :** 
While trying to understand this I also looked up the definition of disjoint events which means "Two events are disjoint if they can't both happen at the same time" so then again
here is what I did (Special here means Jack/king/Queen)

(1 from the 40 and 1 from special) or (1 from the 40 and 2 from special)

$(\binom{40}{1} \times \binom{12}{1}) + (\binom{40}{1} \times \binom{12}{2}) ) $

Which simplifies to $\binom{40}{1} \times (  \binom{12}{1} + \binom{12}{2} ) $

So is the representation of the problem using

**(1 from the 40 and 1 from special) or (1 from the 40 and 2 from special)** wrong ?

Comment: If someone tells you he have at least one card is a jack, queen or a king then this means that it is not possible that he doesn't have a king or a queen or a jack (example: if he does not have a jack or a queen he must be holding a king)

Comment: There are $\binom{52}{2}$ ways to choose two cards. There are $\binom{40}{2}$ ways to choose them so none is J, Q, or K. So an alternate form of the answer is $\binom{52}{2}-\binom{40}{2}$.  In this case, probably a little harder than the way you used, but in other situations the idea of counting complement can save a lot of work.

Comment: This seems rather obvious: the product term $\tbinom{40}1\times\tbinom{12}2$ represents "$1$ card from the remaining stack **and** both cards from Jack/Queen/King", or as you say it in the edit "1 from the 40 and 2 from special". But since only two cards are drawn this is not among the possibilities of the problem, so the term should not be present. A product represents two _independent_ choices, and mutually exclusive (yet individually possible) events are _never_ independent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you expand your first answer, you have
$$
\binom{12}{1} \cdot \binom{40}{1} + \binom{12}{2} \cdot \binom{40}{1}.
$$
Notice in the term on the right, you are choosing a total of three cards, which does not count what you want.

---

A rule of thumb is to turn "at least" problems into several instances of "exactly".

For the problem at hand, "at least one jack/queen/king" translates into "either exactly one jack/queen/king or exactly two jack/queen/king".

The number of ways to get exactly one jack/queen/king and one other card is
$$
\binom{12}{1} \cdot \binom{40}{1}.
$$
We multiply here because you choose a card from the jack/queen/king pile *and* a card from the "other" pile.

The number of ways to get exactly two from jack/queen/king is
$$
\binom{12}{2}.
$$
**Since these cases are disjoint** (this is important), we simply add the results from the two cases. Thus, the number of ways to get at least one Jack, Queen, or King is
$$
\binom{12}{1} \cdot \binom{40}{1} + \binom{12}{2}.
$$

Comment: thanks for the answer , could you explain what you meant by **Notice in the term on the right, you are choosing a total of three cards, which does not count what you want..**

Comment: @MistyD The term $\binom{12}{2} \cdot \binom{40}{1}$ instructs you to select two cards from the jack/queen/king pile *and* one card from the "other" pile, giving you a three-card hand (not a two-card hand, like the problem is asking for).

Comment: Though I partially get what you meant. Lets consider the correct way then $( \binom{40}{1} \times   \binom{12}{1}) + \binom{12}{2} $ . Which I believe means 1 from remaining cards (which is 40) and 1 from J/K/Q , now what does + (mean here) . My mind keeps on asking me why we didn't multiply here instead of adding?

Comment: Addition here corresponds to the _union_ operation on sets; if the sets $A$ and $B$ have no elements in common (this is a critical restriction!) then $|A\cup B| = |A| + |B|$.  In effect what you're saying is that 'all the combinations with at least one JQK' consists of 'all the combinations with *exactly* one JQK' and 'all the combinations with more than one JQK' (in this case there can be only two).

Comment: @MistyD You have two sheets of paper in front of you. The first lists all $\binom{40}{1} \cdot \binom{12}{1}$ hands having exactly one J/Q/K. The second lists all $\binom{12}{2}$ hands having exactly two J/Q/K. Together, the two sheets list all hands having at least one J/Q/K. Thus, to get the total count, you would want to *add* the number of hands in the first list to the number of hands in the second list, not multiply.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to solve this problem is to note that subtracting the number of ways of selecting any two cards neither of which is a Jack, Queen, or King, from the number of ways of selecting any two cards, leaves with the number of ways to pick two cards of which at least one of them is a Jack, Queen, or King.

So,

$$\mbox{(Ways to select any 2 cards from the deck)} - \mbox{(Ways to select 2 cards where neither one is J/Q/K)} = \mbox{Ways to select 2 cards where at least one is J/Q/K}$$

$$\binom{52}{2} - \binom{40}{2} = 1326 - 780 = 546$$

Comment: Thanks for you answer but I am more interested in knowing why I am wrong..

Comment: @ladaghini This answer saves effort, and is more generally useful.  Having a hard time making it work for picking at least 2 of a subgroup when picking 5 form the whole.

Comment: For my situation (15 balls, 8 red, 7 black, 5 chosen) the answer was: 15C5 - (7C4 * 8C1) - 7C5
Where C is combination operation, and the left/right numbers are n/r respectively.

Total combinations - (combainations with 4 black 1 red) - (combaintions 5 black)