# Probability: rolling a fair die

Tags: probability

You roll a fair die 4 times. A success is considered rolling a "6." What is the probability of observing a success in the first roll AND in the last roll?

I know how to calculate the probability of "k" successes in "N" throws but this question seems a little more complex and I'm not sure how to go about solving it.

Comment: You should include some sort of attempt in your question. People will be more willing to help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Probability of rolling sixes in 50 rolls of a fair die](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185241/probability-of-rolling-sixes-in-50-rolls-of-a-fair-die)

Answer (score 2):

Guide:

Assuming each roll is independent.

To determine whether you get successful roll in the first and the last roll. we do not care about the intermediate rolls result.

Hence the question is equivalent to "what is the probability of observing two successes in two rolls".

Comment: Note that this should not be interpreted as "what is the probability of observing two [out of four] successes."

Comment: Thanks for making that clear.